# Estimating distance of user from a camera

Tags: machine-learning, face-detection

Is there a way to use the face detection API and somehow edit it so it can estimate the distance a person is away from the camera?

Comment: It's essentially Pythagoras theorem and similarity of triangles for you. Plenty of work has been done in the area, here's one take https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/A-real-time-face-to-camera-distance-measurement-Hossain-Mukit/b05770faff2f1edf4789f184144baebde5ce78cf I suggest getting back to SO once you have a more specific problem.